# AngularJS : How to update controller scope associated to directive scope's object as it changes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here's the explanation:

I have the current controller that creates an array of $scope.plan.steps which will be used to store every step:

```
.controller('PlanCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.plan = {
        steps: [{}]
    };

    $scope.addStep = function () {
        $scope.tutorial.steps.push({});
    }
}
```

Then I have the following directive which has an isolated scope and that is associated to the index of the $scope.plan.steps array:

```
.directive('planStep', function () {
    return {
        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="step.name" />{{step}}',
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            index: '=index'
        },
        transclude: true,
        controller: function($scope, $element, $transclude) {

            $scope.removeStep = function() {
                $scope.$emit('removeStep', $scope.index);
                $element.remove();
                $scope.$destroy();
            }

        }
    };
});
```

These two communicate, create, and delete objects inside of the controller's scope, however, how can I allow the directive to update the controller's scope array in real time?

I've tried doing a $watch on the directive's isolated scope changes, $emit the changes to the controller, and specify the $index... But no luck.

**I've created a plunker** to reproduce what I currently have:

#### [Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/s6BRYExbSoAK7ibQglUs?p=preview)

So far I can create and delete objects inside of the array, but I cannot get a single object to update the controller's object based on the $index.

If the explanation was not clear, by all means, let me know and I will elaborate.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you set up 2-way binding for index you could set one up for `step` as well? And you really do not need index to remove the item, eventhough your directive is isolated it relies on the index from ng-repeat which probably is not a good idea.

```
<plan-step ng-repeat="step in plan.steps" index="$index" step="step"></plan-step>
```

and in your directive:

```
scope: {
    index: '=index',
    step:'='
 },
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/tRdCxh?p=preview)**

Removing $index dependency and redundant element remove() and scope destroy (when the item is removed from the array angular will manage it by itself):

```
 return {
  template: '<button  ng-click="removeStep()">Delete step</button><br><input type="text" ng-model="step.name" />{{step}}<br><br>',
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
    step:'='
  },
  transclude: true,
  controller: function($scope, $element, $transclude) {
    $scope.removeStep = function() {
      $scope.$emit('removeStep', $scope.step);
    }
  }
```

and in your controller:

```
 $scope.$on('removeStep', function(event, data) {
  var steps = $scope.plan.steps;
  steps.splice(steps.indexOf(data), 1);
});
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/jPhF6w?p=preview)**

If you want to get rid of $emit you could even expose an api with the isolated scoped directive with function binding (&).

```
return {
  template: '<button  ng-click="onDelete({step:step})">Delete step</button><br><input type="text" ng-model="step.name" />{{step}}<br><br>',
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
    step:'=',
    onDelete:'&' //Set up function binding
  },
  transclude: true
};
```

and register it on the view:

```
<plan-step ng-repeat="step in plan.steps"  step="step" on-delete="removeStep(step)"></plan-step>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/MZF4np?p=preview)**

Comment: @TiffanyLowe Assuming this is what you wanted (as i understand your question), yup, you have many options available as well. BTW you are in a very old angular world.. :)

Comment: I grabbed that template from Plunkr, I'm always up to date. :)

Answer (score 3):

WHen you do things like this inside `ng-repeat` you can take advantage of the child scope that ng-repeat creates and work without isolated scope.

Here's the same directive without needing any angular events

```
.directive('planStep', function() {
    return {
      template: '<button  ng-click="removeStep(step)">Delete step</button><br><input type="text" ng-model="step.name" />{{step}}<br><br>',
      restrict: 'E',          
      transclude: true,
      controller: function($scope, $element, $transclude) {
       var steps =  $scope.plan.steps// in scope from main controller
        /* can do the splicing here if we want*/
        $scope.removeStep = function(step) {
          var idx =steps.indexOf(step) 
           steps.splice(idx, 1);
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

Also note that removing the element with element.remove() is redundant since it will automatically be removed by angular when array gets spliced

As for the update, it will update the item in real time

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/OSUQFA?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Yup we can do that, but separation of concerns violation probably. :)

Comment: like to hear what you mean about that

Comment: This directive will be less reusable it knows too much, it knows that parent has a property called a plan and it has steps property and so on. Instead of controller which manages the steps, directive directly goes upon the parent set property and does something on it, which probably is unintended and will be less reusable and maintainable. There is a lot of assumption this directive takes (if i rename my property on the parent i need to know that there is one directive that is tightly coupled as well). But yes this will _Work_

Comment: ok, makes sense. i've done this quite a bit . Lately lots of buzz about minimizing use of isolated scope. I always took philosophy of trying not to isolate unless it was imperative and liked the simplicity of using parent

Comment: oh no you are right. Infact isolated does not mean that that is only reusable thing. But i always think twice before trying to directly access a property on its parent especially if it modifies it, and not to rely on any other directive used along with this one (eg: ng-repeat).